# Python project using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m a 200l student trying to work on a project that says ‘ draw an outdoor scene with windows’ I’ve been struggling a bit because I don’t know where to begin. I’d appreciate all the help I can get here thanks.

Comment: read this first : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sainita Just so you know, you can more easily generate that link with `[ask]`: [ask].

Comment: perhaps it would be a loophole, but can't you draw the scene in MS Paint or sth similar and then just display it on the window? unless the task specifically says to create the scene using a GUI toolkit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just so you know in the future, recommendation questions are off-topic here. If you have a specific problem with the specific code you have tried, we will be happy to help. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried, along with any problems/errors it may have.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Wow, wish I had known that earlier! For anyone else out there wondering about these, I found a whole list of them in the [help]: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting. One I know I'm definitely going to use is `[example]` (much easier than typing out `[minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible/example)` which I've been doing this whole time).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin `[mcve]` is the shortcut I use for that. I didn't even know about `[example]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are drawing a scene rather creating a UI with tkinter, I would recommend creating a canvas. Look for python code in the [canvas docs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html). (You should also look at tkinter tutorials). You will probably want `canvas.create_rectangle` for creating windows in your outdoor scene.

Here is a basic tkinter app with a canvas with a rectangle drawn on to get you started:

```
import tkinter as tk

def draw(canvas):
    # draw a rectangle with one corner at  (10,10) and the other at (100,100)
    # ((0,0) is the top left of the window)
    canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,100,100,fill='white')

def main():
    # setup a window with a canvas that has a blue background
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='blue')
    canvas.pack()
    # call the draw function defined above
    draw(canvas)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```